# Can you change password in Wasabi Wallet?

Tags: passphrase, wasabi-wallet

Can users change wallet password in Wasabi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can change the password (with code currently.) Let's assume you already did. In that case note that Wasabi used your old password as the passphrase (the 13th mnemonic word) and while you can change your password, you cannot change your passphrase, so the 13th word will stay your old password.